# Show Content Based on Number of list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a load more link to load more list items on a page using AJAX. Currently there is a 'hide' class on the link to hide it by default.

I would, however, like to show the 'load more' link when there is more than a certain number.

```
<ul class="myClass">
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
</ul>

<p class="hide" id="load-more">Load More</p>
```

Perhaps I'm overthinking it. Help is appreciated:

```
var n = $("ul.myClass").length;
var loadmore = $("#load-more");

if (n > 8) {
  loadmore.removeClass("hide");
}
```

Comment: do you mean `ul .myClass` (with a space in between)? Are you trying to count `ul`'s or `li`'s?

Comment: dang ... yea, I missed the ul.myClass li -- trying to count the ```li```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Needs to be `var n = $("ul.myClass li").length;`, assuming your list items are what you're attempting to count, not the `<ul>` container

Comment: Yep - just caught that.